# How to show 2 search possibilities on an Android app bar?

Tags: mobile, android, search

Here, need an advise on some layouts I’m working on:
We have a mobile app (tablet only) used by doctors to access patients registered via a desktop app. Recently, we added biometric registration for these patients and I need to compliment for this addition on the App Bar.

The first challenge is to design the app bar in a way that makes the doctors aware that they can now search for patients via fingerprint, it used to be via name/I.D. Here are the screens I’m exploring.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any information about the fingerprint shown in the search textfields once a patient has put his/her finger?

Answer (score 2):

*I think this highly depends on how the fingerprint search works. This answer is based on the assumption that you use the hardware based fingerprint reader in a table device.*

---

As I see it right now there could be two possible options:

**Method 1: Press fingerprint-field first**

1. The user presses the button (no matter where it is positioned)
2. The search box is opened and the user can scan a finger print
3. The fingerprint is scanned and the search results are shown

**Method 2: Scan fingerprint first**

1. The fingerprint is scanned and the search results are shown

Obviously, the second method is much shorter and saves interaction time. You should consider there is that the user should know that the fingerprint scanner can be used. A way to do this could be by having the button available as in your 3rd proposal. If the user taps this, a simple popup can be shown that indicates how the system should be used.

*Downside there is that the user can accidentally press the fingerprint reader, causing the system to search directly.*

My suggestion would be to test this with your users.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are a lot of different factors to consider but at a glance I'm drawn to your second solution with the field labels. I think a small icon might not be noticed by users whereas the explanatory text shows quickly what each field will do.